# Oracle to MySQL migration using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Is there any available/aiding tool in java/Spring to do read data from Oracle (old/existing table structure), do some transformation and basically send to Spring-data-REST exposed MySQL database(new table structure).

Basically, want to build a Spring boot application/service which does the same. 
P.S.,we have a audit log table in Oracle which we want to use it to drive/sync from Oracle to MySQL.

Does Flyway support this?

Thanks
Bharath